# Equal height image grid that fills up width of container

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

- 1 row with 3 images inside.
- 1 row with 2 images inside.

How can I make the images within the 100%-width-container have equal height?

None of the images have a consistent width and height.
I need the images to maintain their cropping and aspect-ratio.
They don't need to have equal width.

Here's what I've achieved with flex-box so far. But they don't have equal height. I don't mind using JavaScript to solve this.

I'd rather not set a height-value for the container or image.
Is there a way for the images to distribute itself equally while having same height?

```css
.wrapper {
  width:100vw; /*should be width of browser*/
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:1px solid;
}

.image {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 50px 1.5%;
}
.image:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}
.image:last-child {
  margin-right:0;
}
img {
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper three_images">
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/800/"></li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/850/"></li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/550/700/"></li>
</ul>



<ul class="wrapper two_images">
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/800/"></li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/850/"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Basically, you can't do this with **inline** images without distorting the images.

Comment: whats an alternative instead of inline images?

Comment: Which image should be scaled if they have different height?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using jQuery :

```
$(".wrapper").each(function () {
  /** Push all images size in an array **/
  let imagesSize = [];
  $(this)
    .find("img")
    .each(function () {
      let imgWidth = $(this).width();
      let imgHeight = $(this).height();
      imagesSize.push([imgWidth, imgHeight]);
    });

  /** Assign the same height to all the images **/
  let newImagesSize = [];
  let totalWidth = 0;
  let referenceHeight = imagesSize[0][1];

  imagesSize.forEach(function (imageSize, index) {
    let heightRatio = referenceHeight / imageSize[1];
    let newImgWidth = imageSize[0] * heightRatio;
    let newImgHeight = imageSize[1] * heightRatio;
    newImagesSize.push([newImgWidth, newImgHeight]);
    totalWidth += newImgWidth;
  });

  /** Get the total width of all the images, the width of the wrapper and addapt the width/height of each images **/
  let wrapperWidth = $(this).width();
  let widthRatio = wrapperWidth / totalWidth;

  $(this)
    .find("img")
    .each(function (index, el) {
      let imgWidth = newImagesSize[index][0] * widthRatio;
      let imgHeight = newImagesSize[index][1] * widthRatio;
      $(this).css({ width: imgWidth, height: imgHeight });
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".wrapper").each(function (index, el) {
    /** Push all images size in an array **/
    let imagesSize = [];
    $(this)
      .find("img")
      .each(function () {
        let imgWidth = $(this).width();
        let imgHeight = $(this).height();
        imagesSize.push([imgWidth, imgHeight]);
      });

    /** Assign the same height to all the images **/
    let newImagesSize = [];
    let totalWidth = 0;
    let referenceHeight = imagesSize[0][1];

    imagesSize.forEach(function (imageSize, index) {
      let heightRatio = referenceHeight / imageSize[1];
      let newImgWidth = imageSize[0] * heightRatio;
      let newImgHeight = imageSize[1] * heightRatio;
      newImagesSize.push([newImgWidth, newImgHeight]);
      totalWidth += newImgWidth;
    });

    /** Get the total width of all the images, the width of the wrapper and addapt the width/height of each images **/
    let wrapperWidth = $(this).width();
    let widthRatio = wrapperWidth / totalWidth;

    $(this)
      .find("img")
      .each(function (index, el) {
        let imgWidth = newImagesSize[index][0] * widthRatio;
        let imgHeight = newImagesSize[index][1] * widthRatio;
        $(this).css({ width: imgWidth, height: imgHeight });
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.image {
  float: left;
}

li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="wrapper three_images">
  <li class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x750.jpeg/FFFF00"></li>
  <li class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300.jpeg/0000FF"></li>
  <li class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x550.jpeg/FF0000"></li>
</ul>



<ul class="wrapper two_images">
  <li class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x800.jpeg/808080"></li>
  <li class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x850.jpeg/dddddd"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413287/my-answer-was-deleted-but-im-not-sure-why?cb=1)

Comment: Note that SO has built-in support for live demos of Javascript/CSS/HTML. There's no need to link to an external site for that. Linking to external sites should be avoided, it's preferred to keep answers on-site.

Comment: [when I run the snippet in safari, it doesn't quite look to fit the requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxV9S.png)

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it doesn't seem correct as well on my side.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and size img on both axis , it will crop itself :

You can also tune this with [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position), [image-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation) , [image-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)

```
img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width:100vw; /*should be width of browser*/
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:1px solid;
}
body {margin:0;}

.image {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 50px 1.5%;
}
.image:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}
.image:last-child {
  margin-right:0;
}
img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper three_images">
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/800/"></li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/850/"></li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/550/700/"></li>
</ul>



<ul class="wrapper two_images">
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/800/"></li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/850/"></li>
</ul>
```

See: https://caniuse.com/object-fit

The way it works is basicly like if image is set in background and sized via background-size, background-position, but only alike , behavior and semantic are just not alike :(

Comment: just wanted to check, when i use object-fit cover, is there faux-cropping of the images?

Comment: @wsgg yes image are cropped wherever needed, else ratio is lost , object-position can help tune which side(s) should be cropped

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
  width:100vw; /*should be width of browser*/
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:1px solid;
}

.image {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 50px 1.5%;
  height: 100px; /* SET THIS */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}
.image:last-child {
  margin-right:0;
}
img {
  width:100%
  height: 100%;
}
```

Try this. simply set the .image height value to whatever you feel comfortable with.

Comment: I forgot to mention that rather not set a height-value for the container or image. 

Is there a way for the images to distribute itself equally while having same height?

Comment: ah no, i mentioned in the question that "I need the images to maintain their cropping and aspect-ratio."

hmm thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer:

```css
       .flex-container{
            max-width:100%;
            display: flex;
            overflow: hidden;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: -2.5px;
        }
        .flex-container:after {
            content: '';
            flex-grow: 999999999;
            min-width: 300px;
            height: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .flex-item{
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            height: 16vw;
            margin: 3px;
            flex-grow: 1;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .flex-item img{
            height: 16vw;
            object-fit: cover;
            max-width: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            overflow-clip-margin: content-box;
            overflow: clip;
        }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
      <a class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://www.uu.nl/sites/default/files/styles/image_1085x580/public/6e3dfc45%20BAMA-shoot_GW_Tim-Vermeire_2022_048Lage%20resolutie%20%281%29.jpg" height="100">
      </a>
      <a class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://www.uu.nl/sites/default/files/styles/image_270x180/public/uu_merkindex_positionering.jpg" height="100">
      </a>
      <a class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://www.uu.nl/sites/default/files/styles/image_1085x580/public/6e3dfc45%20BAMA-shoot_GW_Tim-Vermeire_2022_048Lage%20resolutie%20%281%29.jpg" height="100">
      </a>
      <a class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://www.uu.nl/sites/default/files/styles/image_1085x580/public/7daad040%20Overzicht-David-de-Wiedgebouw_Dick_Boetekees_20150414_65Lage%20resolutie.jpg" height="100">
      </a>
      <a class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://www.uu.nl/sites/default/files/styles/image_1085x580/public/6e3dfc45%20BAMA-shoot_GW_Tim-Vermeire_2022_048Lage%20resolutie%20%281%29.jpg" height="100">
      </a>
</div>
```